# Why would I not want to set ENABLE_BROKER?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I've just noticed that most of the databases used by a webapp built with entity framework, have the SQL Option ENABLE_BROKER set to ON.

Is this normal?  What are the implications of setting this for all databases, or alternatively disabling it for all databases?
Is there overheads involved, if not is it safe to set it for everthhing?

I don't really understand its purpose and effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service Broker is enabled by default when new databases are created with T-SQL (e.g. `CREATE DATABASE NewDatabase;`).  However, SQL Server Management Studio honors the SB option specified on the options page of the Create Database dialog, which defaults to false.  Service Broker is disabled following a restore or attach, requiring a subsequent `ALTER DATABASE` with the `NEW_BROKER` or `ENABLE_BROKER` option in order to enable SB.

The cost is near zero when SB is enabled but not used. Disabling SB un user databases will of course prevent applications from using the feature directly for queueing and async message processing as well as components like SqlDependency/QueryNotifications that rely on it.  The msdb system database uses SB for features like database mail.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's set on by default for new databases. That may be true in your environment if you turned that setting on for the model database, but it doesn't appear to be set that way with a default install. Also, turning service broker on and off requires an exclusive database lock. So toggling it is not something to be entered into lightly!

Comment: @BenThul, I updated my answer to clarify that it is SSMS that toggles the option, not SQL Server.  Real DBAs use T-SQL :-)